# Can you help me to find a counter example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be sets and let $f$ and $g$ be functions such that: $g : X \to Y$
and $f : Y \to Z$. Prove or give a counterexample for the following claims.

1. If $f$ is onto, then $f\circ g$ is onto.
2. If $g$ is onto, then $f\circ g$ is onto.

I showed that f is onto but I tried to find a counterexample for g is onto
Is that ok to say: Let's take $X=Y=\{0,1\}$, $Z=\{0\}$, so $g(0)=g(1)=f(0)=f(1)=0$ then $f$ and $f\circ g$ are onto but not $g$?

Comment: How do you showed that $f$ is onto? Also, your example shows that the statement "if $f$ and $f \circ g$ are onto, then $g$ is onto" is false, but that's not what the problem is about.

Comment: Using $X= \{0,1\}=Y=Z$ and $f(0)=0, f(1)=1, g(0)=g(1)=0$ we get that $f$ is onto but $f \circ g$ is not. Changing the role of $f$ and $g$ gives a counterexample for the second part.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title that relates to the actual content more specifically.

Comment: So, if I said that is it wrong?
if f is onto, then fog is onto:
F:Y-->Z, g:X-->Y and g(x)belongs to Y
F:Y-->Z, for all z belongs to Z, there is a ybelongs to Y g(x) such that f(y)=Z
f(g(x))=Z, for all z belongs to Z

2. Consider X={x}, y={y,z}, Z={d}
so {x}-->g-->{y,z}-->f-->{d}. Then g(y)=g(z)=d and g(f(x)) is valid for f(x)=y or f(x)=z. Therefore, there cannot be an element in X,for all Y and g:X-->Y cannot be onto
for example: X=Y={0,1}, Z={0} and g(0)=g(1)=f(0)=f(1)=0

Answer (score 1):

I will give you the solution for $1.$, in order to prove this is wrong we need an onto function $f: Y\to Z$ and any function $g: X \to Y$ such that $f \circ g : X \to Z$ is not onto. Let $X = Y = Z$ be any set and let $a \in X$ be an element and define $g:X \to X$ with $g(x) = a$ $\forall x\in X$ and let $f$ be the identity function, clearly $$f\circ g(x) = f(g(x)) = f(a) = a$$ so $f\circ g$ is not onto but $f$ is identity function and hence onto, giving us the counterexample.